# Setup BlueZ GATT Server with random address?

Tags: bluez, gatt

I followed GATT_Server example and advertisment example provided in BlueZ and built a GATT server in Python and it works fine.

I wanted to setup GATT server to use Random address instead of public address. adapter-api and device-api has AddressType field but it is read-only and I can't change it to Random.

Is it possible to setup BlueZ GATT server with Random address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was having a similar problem. Here's how I solved my problem:

After a lot of searching, I found that PyBluez just uses gattlib for all ble stuff: [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/OscarAcena/pygattlib)

I was able to connect to my device with the following: (python 2.7)

```
import gattlib
requester = gattlib.GATTRequester('EF:76:B5:CC:36:A0', False)
reqer.connect(True, channel_type='random')
```

I know it's not the same as your problem, but I'm hoping it might help anyways.